# Excel; compute average within each group?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Consider a toy data set in the form of

```
 A    B
ID values
 1    5
 1    4
 1    3
 2    2
 2    1
 2    2
 3    8
 3    9
 3    7
```

So there are three groups there with ID: 1,2,3  I'm interested in compute the averaged value within each each group and have result like this

```
A       B
ID      averaged
1       6
2       2.5
3       12
```

So the number of groups (unique ID) would be large and number of data within each group also large. Any efficient way of computing ? Thanks

Comment: use `=averageif()` or `=averageifs()`

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter this array (CSE) formula in cell `J11`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($H$11:$H$24, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($J$10:J10, $H$11:$H$24), 0)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.** Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill down.

- Formula in cell `K11`:

  `=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(H$11:H$24,$J11,I$11:I$24),"")`

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply; but I try your example; `IFERROR` is always evaluate to `True`

Comment: @ElleryL,, use properly it's working,, once work with data I've shown!!

Comment: @ElleryL,, formula in Cell `J11` is an array formula finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

Comment: @ElleryL, glad to help you ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

Using a pivot table:

Put the ID in the Rows and the Values in Values and change to average:

[image]

---

Using the dynamic array formulas(Currently only available to Office 365 Insiders)

In D2 put:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A10)
```

And in E2:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,D2#)
```

Excel will spill the values down automatically:

[image]